# Gelfand-Kirillov dimension for non-associative algebras

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, non-associative-algebras

Let $A$ be any finitely generated algebra - non necessarely unital neither associative - over a base field $k$. Let us denote the product $*$. Suppose $A$ is finitely generated by $S$, and introduce $A_1 = span \langle S \rangle$ if $A$ is not unital; $A_1 = span \langle S \rangle + k$ if it is unital. Let $A_n = A_{n-1} + \sum_{v+u=n} A_u * A_v$. The Gelfand-Kirillov dimension of $A$ is:

$GK \, A = lim \, sup_{\, n \mapsto \infty} \frac{log \, dim A_n}{log \, n}$.

This invariant is thoroughly studied for associative algebras, such as in the classic book of Krause and Lenagan, **[** *Growth of algebras and Gelfand-Kirillov dimension* (revised edition) **]**.

The Gelfand-Kirillov dimension for Lie algebras has also been considered for Lie algebras by V. Petrogradsky and others (cf. Krause and Lenagan **[** op. cit. **]**, Section 12.1).

For Jordan algebras, I've found references in:

- C. Martinez, **[** *Gelʹfand-Kirillov dimension in Jordan algebras*, **MR1329537** **]** (this paper also has one result on the Gelfand-Kirillov dimension of alternative algebras).
- C. Martinez, E. Zelmanov, **[** *Jordan algebras of Gelʹfand-Kirillov dimension one*, **MR1375577** **]**

In am interested in

**References** for the Gelfand-Kirillov dimension of general non necessarely unital neither associative algebras; in particular, for the Gelfand-Kirillov dimension of alternative and Malcev algebras.

The only work I know of that discuss things is this generality is Ufnarovskij **[** *Combinatorial and asymptotic methods in algebra*, Algebra, VI, 1–196, Encyclopaedia Math. Sci., 57 **MR1060321** **]**, but it is somewhat outdated for this pourpuse.

Any comments or references on this subject are very much welcomed.